# How to check if a particular skill already exists in table, and then add that skill id to another table?

Tags: python, postgresql, api, rest, fastapi

I have to create a new API for an employee portal. I have two tables **emp_skills** (columns: **id, emp_id, skill_id**) and **skills_master** (columns: **skill_id, skill_name**).

First I have to check if a particular skill that the employee is adding to their info already exists in the **skills_master** table, if it does then just add that **skill_id** to **emp_skills** table. If it does not, then add as new entry in the **skills_master** table.

I have done the below and the error I am getting is:

> Exception occurred while adding employees 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

```
skill_name = req_json.skill_name
validation_query = """select count(skill_name) from skills_master where skill_name='{skill_name}'""".format(skill_name=skill_name)
output = RDBMSUtility().execute_select_query(validation_query)

if output[0][0] != 0:
    query4 = f"""select skill_id from skills_master where skill_name = '{req_json.skill_name}'"""
    output3 = RDBMSUtility().execute_query(query4, True)
    skill_id = output3[0][0]
    RDBMSUtility().update_table("emp_skills", f""" "skill_id" = '{skill_id[0]}'
                                """, f"emp_id = '{req_json.emp_id}'")

else:
    query5 = f"""insert into skills_master ("skill_name") VALUES ('{skill_name}')"""
    RDBMSUtility().execute_query(query5, False)
```

Comment: Sooo ... what did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Hello, updated in the question, pls check

Answer (score 1):

The result of your query is `None` and you are trying to use it as a `list` object.

First check if your raw query works in `RDB` and what is the result. then check the `validation_query` string is written correctly in python, maybe with a simple print. Then use a `try/except` block.